# How to represent -0 in binary

Tags: binary, fixed-point, negative-number

This question concerns converting a floating point number that is less than abs(1) and negative to 32.32 format, for example: -0.1234.

When this is converted to 32.32, the integer portion and fractional portion are separated into the upper and lower 32 bit words, respectively.  In this example above, the upper 32-bits will hold -0, while the lower will hold .1234, both converted to binary.

So the question is, in this case, how does one properly represent the -0 value in binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

- [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), there is no such thing as -0.
- [One's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One%27s_complement), -0 is represented by all '1's.
- [Sign-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign-magnitude), -0 is represented by a sign bit of '1', and all other bits as '0'.

Comment: Good point.  This question arose from a customer's requirements that specified the number format to use when storing double values into an EEPROM.  Interestingly, the requirement does say to encode numbers in "32.32 2's complement format".  Being 2's complement, how then could a value of -0.1234 be encoded and written to the EEPROM, then retrieved and decoded without losing the negative sign?

Comment: @doug: The way to think of "32.32" is that it will represent some number `x` in exactly the same way as "64.0" would store `x * (1L << 32)`.

Answer (score 0):

`+0 == 0 == -0` for practical purposes of programming. In this case, you would have to figure out how negative numbers are being handled but the underlying system. ( Generally either [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) or [sign bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) ) and monkey with that accordingly.