# What is 32.32 format?

Tags: binary

I encountered a document (a physical one so I cannot provide a link) that specified a number be stored in a "byte format" called "32.32 2's Complement". While I know what two's complement is I've never heard 32.32 in the context of a number format. I assume it is another name for something I've heard of but google was no help.

Comment: It's presumably denoting a 64-bit fixed-point representation, with 32 integer bits and 32 fractional bits.

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067590/how-to-represent-0-in-binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation is often used for fixed point numbers. If it was specified as `Q32.32` it would be unambiguous, with 32 bits of integer and 32 bits of fraction. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to refer to a floating-point representation, with 32-bit base and 32-bit exponent (64-bits in total).

See [Numbers, by Dr. Simon Spacey](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~sspacey/teaching/COMP311/_/pdf/2.%20Numbers.pdf) (page 5)

Comment: You provided an good resource on floating point representation, which uses the same format to describe how the bits are broken down. Mark's answer however explicitly defined the format description which more directly answers my question.